# notify-send terminates after Chinese characters

Tags: bash, unicode, notify-send

In trying to generate a notification with `notify-send` i am noticing that inputting a Chinese character seems to terminate the notification.

I am trying to achieve a multi-line notification and can do so in normal text using

```
notify-send "Heading" "line1 \n line2 \n line3"
```

producing a notification like this:

```
Heading
line1
line2
line3
```

Including Chinese characters allows them to appear in the notification, but then will not allow any new line creation afterwards

```
notify-send "Heading" "line1 \n 某事 \n line3"
```

produces:

```
Heading
line1
某事
```

with the third line missing.

Any way I can overcome this?

Strangely, If i make the third line also characters, it works:

```
notify-send "Heading" "line1 \n 某事 \n 某事"
```

gives:

```
Heading
line1
某事
某事
```

Comment: Can't reproduce on Ubuntu 18.04. Which OS is this?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 and notify-send notify-send 0.7.6

Comment: Works for me, notify-send 0.7.8